# Gulp Uncss won't complete

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

I was hoping to eventually set up a Gulp workflow with uncss as I have a lot of unused Bootstrap styles in my sites. I am trying to test some files first though and when I run it, it starts but just hangs and never stops. I got the code directly from the plugin page so I'm not sure what is going on. I haven't added anything more complicated yet. Does anyone see errors?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uncss = require('gulp-uncss');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/landing.css')
    .pipe(uncss({
        html: ['index.html']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('out'));
});
```

Comment: I have tried it using the gulpfile example in NPM page and have tried your gulp file above and it works in my tests.  Of course it would be a better test using your HTML and CSS. That may provide more information to help you reach an answer.

Comment: Thank you. I tried on another project folder and it worked right away. Strange but maybe a bad install of the plugins or something on the above project.